# Sapper/Svelte possible to conditionally import components?

Tags: svelte, sapper

In Sapper I am trying to import a component only if being rendered client side (using `onMount`). Is there something similar to React `Suspense` and  `React.lazy`? Or is there another approach?

Comment: I know a library called [svelte-lazy](https://github.com/leafOfTree/svelte-lazy) which enable to do lazy loading.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can certainly do it that way, yes:

```html
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
  let Thing;
    
  onMount(async () => {
    Thing = (await import('./Thing.svelte')).default;
  });
</script>

<svelte:component this={Thing} answer={42}>
  <p>some slotted content</p>
</svelte:component>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/16b375da9b39417dae837b5006799cb4?version=3.25.0).

Alternatively, you could wrap that into a component:

```html
<!-- Loader.svelte -->
<script>
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    
  let loader;
  let Component;
    
  onMount(async () => {
    Component = (await loader()).default;
  });
    
  export { loader as this };
</script>

<svelte:component this={Component} {...$$restProps}>
  <slot></slot>
</svelte:component>

{#if !Component}
  <slot name="fallback"></slot>
{/if}
```

```html
<Loader
  this={() => import('./Thing.svelte')}
  answer={42}
>
  <p>some slotted content</p>
  <p slot="fallback">loading...</p>
</Loader>
```

[Demo here](https://svelte.dev/repl/c2f6ef6b1b194467945d5f9c48b779b8?version=3.25.0). A caveat with this approach is that slots other than `default` won't be 'forwarded' to the underlying component.

Comment: is there any way to make it SSR? That would be very useful for web apps where UI depends on the existence of auth cookies for example. Currently, with CSR only import, it's causing Layout Shift.